# Two graphics and the same chart

Tags: asp.net, charts

I want to add a spline graphic and a points graphic on the same asp.net chart. Can somebody show an explicite example of how you do that?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would be nice to know if you want a C# or a Visual Basic example. I've got a Visual Basic one for you. (You could convert it to C# with an online converter). I hope this helps you.

.aspx file:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">

    <div>
        <asp:Chart ID="Chart1" runat="server">
            <ChartAreas>
                <asp:ChartArea Name="ChartArea1"></asp:ChartArea>
            </ChartAreas>
        </asp:Chart>
    </div>

</form>
```

.vb file:

```
Imports System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting
Imports System.Drawing

Public Class ChartExample
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

Private Sub Page_load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    ' Add the title
    Chart1.Titles.Add("Title1")

    ' Set the text of the title
    Chart1.Titles("Title1").Text = "Chart Area 1 Title"

    ' Dock the title to a ChartArea
    Chart1.Titles("Title1").DockedToChartArea = "ChartArea1"

    ' Creating the series
    Dim series1 As New Series("Series1")
    Dim series2 As New Series("Series2")

    ' Setting the Chart Type
    series1.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Spline
    series2.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Point

    ' Adding some points
    series1.Points.AddXY(0, 10)
    series1.Points.AddXY(5, 16)
    series1.Points.AddXY(10, 9)
    series1.Points.AddXY(15, 32)
    series1.Points.AddXY(20, 21)

    series2.Points.AddXY(0, 5)
    series2.Points.AddXY(5, 12)
    series2.Points.AddXY(10, 18)
    series2.Points.AddXY(15, 11)
    series2.Points.AddXY(20, 25)

    ' Add the series to the chart
    Chart1.Series.Add(series1)
    Chart1.Series.Add(series2)

    ' Set the chart's height and width
    Chart1.Width = 600
    Chart1.Height = 600

    ' Setting the X Axis
    Chart1.ChartAreas("ChartArea1").AxisX.IsMarginVisible = True
    Chart1.ChartAreas("ChartArea1").AxisX.Interval = 1
    Chart1.ChartAreas("ChartArea1").AxisX.Maximum = [Double].NaN
    Chart1.ChartAreas("ChartArea1").AxisX.Title = "x"
    Chart1.ChartAreas("ChartArea1").AxisX.TitleFont = New Font("Sans Serif", 10, FontStyle.Bold)

    ' Setting the Y Axis
    Chart1.ChartAreas("ChartArea1").AxisY.Interval = 2
    Chart1.ChartAreas("ChartArea1").AxisY.Maximum = [Double].NaN
    Chart1.ChartAreas("ChartArea1").AxisY.Title = "y"
    Chart1.ChartAreas("ChartArea1").AxisY.TitleFont = New Font("Sans Serif", 10, FontStyle.Bold)

End Sub

End Class
```